# select2 not working in jquery steps

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-steps

I using jQuery Steps and jQuery select2
I using select2  in step 1 and step 2 
In step 1 select 2 working and looking great
In step 2 select 2 not working and looking like regular drop down list
How can i fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You can place init code of other plugins after the STEPS,

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
   $("#form").steps({....});
   var form =$("#form");
   form.find(".select2").select2();
   var mapAddr = form.find("input[name='contact_addr']");
   mapAddr.geocomplete({...});
   var resetBtn = form.find("#reset");
   resetBtn.click(function(){.....});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

actually the problem is that jquery step changes `id of html elements`
 with its own custom id's for movement of elements , back and forth, check by inspect element you will find that element id have been changed, and Selector chain may be have been broke.